# how to call a form, which is define as a service, from the controller?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

how can I call a form (which is defined as a service) from the controller

```
//Here my code in the controller befor I define Form_NameType() as a service
$form = $this->createForm(new Form_NameType(), $obect_that_hydrate_my_form);
```

.

```
 // SERVICE
 blogbundle.Form_Nameform:
    class: BlogBundle\Form\Form_NameType
    arguments: [@security.context]
    tags:
      - {name: form.type, alias: FormAsAService }
```

Answer (score 0):

To call any service in `Symfony` you need to use `get` method of `ContainerInterface`. So in `Controller` class you should call:

```
$form = $this->container->get('blogbundle.Form_Nameform');
```

If your `Controller` extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` then there is an alias for that method, and you can use this syntax (which is shorter):

```
$form = $this->get('blogbundle.Form_Nameform');
```

Check [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container) of how to use services.

Answer (score 0):

I just found how to do it... I tried before but I mispelled it so could not work.

```
$form = $this->createForm( 'FormAsAService' , $obect_that_hydrate_my_form);
```

FormAsAService is the name define in the service as an Alias and should be the same as the name define in the form class in the getName() function.

```
public function getName(){ return 'FormAsAService';}
```